# Include files from a domain to another inside same server on PHP

Tags: php, dns, include, virtualhost

I have a server with two domains using VHost and it'd be really helpful if I could include files from a domain to another.

Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Can you access your file system? Just point to the other folder path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP's [`include()`](http://php.net/include) directive uses file system locations. There's nothing stopping you from including whatever file you want to.